# How should I transform multiple key/value columns in a scikit-learn pipeline?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'd like to build a sklearn pipeline to transform data that contains multiple key/value pairs:

```
import pandas as pd
D = pd.DataFrame([ ['a', 1, 'b', 2], ['b', 2, 'c', 3]], columns = ['k1', 'v1', 'k2', 'v2'])
print(D)
```

Output:

```
  k1  v1 k2  v2
0  a   1  b   2
1  b   2  c   3
```

[`DictVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html) seems appropriate but I'm struggling with transforming multiple key/value columns present on each row into a suitable dict for processing.

`DictVectorizer` seems amenable to input like this:

```
row1 = {'a':1, 'b':2}
row2 = {'b':2, 'c':3}
data = [row1, row2]
# This is the output structure that I need:
print(data)
```

yielding:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'b': 2}]
```

Then it will transform into an array like this:

```
DictVectorizer( sparse=False ).fit_transform(data)
```

Final output:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  3.]])
```

What would be a suitable custom transformer to transform multiple key/value pairs as shown above?

Comment: So, just to clarify, you're looking to turn a pandas DataFrame with these pairs of K/V columns into a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Yes. I'm stumbling around with the python-speak coming from an R background. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about a special transformer but you could use a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> data = [{row['k1']:row['v1'], row['k2']:row['v2']} for index, row in D.iterrows()]
>>> data
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'b': 2}]
```

From here you could use a dict vectorizer like this:

```
>>> v = sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
>>> X = v.fit_transform(data)
>>> print X
[[ 1.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  3.]]
```

Comment: I implemented a transformer inspired by your approach: [gist](https://gist.github.com/872f9431de3e37b65682). To get it to work with a configurable set of columns I tweaked it a bit. Thank you!

Comment: @BradDixon pretty neat stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Building on Mike's answer (which is definitely more elegant than my original one), you can use the same logic of pairs of columns and avoid having to specify each pair with the following:

```
[dict((row[i-1],row[i]) for i in np.arange(1,len(D.columns),2)) for index, row in D.iterrows() ]
```

This yields the following:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'b': 2}]
```

**Note:** This assumes that the pairs are organized like in your example (k1,v1,k2,v2, etc) and that there are an even number of columns.